# Go through all the userforms of a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to write a VBA program that prints the name of all the userforms in a workbook.

For instance, if a workbook has a userform called `frmHello`. I just want to print `UserForm: frmHello`

[image]

Does anyone know which collection is about userforms, and how to find the name of a userform?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to get the basics [here](www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx), about programming the VBE.  This would allow you to iterate over the `VBComponents` collection in the Workbook's `VBProject`.  Then you can check each component for `Type = vbext_ct_MSForm`, and print your list accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one works for me:

```
Dim c As Object
For Each c In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
     If c.Type = 3 Then
         MsgBox c.Name
     End If
Next
```

Comment: note that this (if not in an addin) requires an additional security permission (Excel Options > Trust Centre > Macro Settings > Trust access to the VBA Project object model)

Comment: Thanks, @Cor_Blimey, it's valuable comment:)