# Re-Opening a user form with a variable

Tags: vba, userform

I'm trying to get a Userform to open after it's been hidden or unloaded (Can't get either to work)

Note: All User Forms are Called "frmSetup" & i

So all but frmSetup0 have a cancel button. When this cancel button is click it unloads the current form and loads up frmSetup0 which is a glorified "are you sure?" If the user selects no, I need it to reload the form they where last on.

As far as I understand vba.userforms only accounts for current active forms. So I can't use that to check for the form in a loop. Like this:

```
Dim Obj As Object, Str As String
Str = "frmSetup" & i

For Each Obj In VBA.UserForms
    If Obj.Name = Str Then Obj.Show
Next
```

So is there a way to take a string: "frmSetup" & i and get it to load the relevant userform?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go through all the userforms of a workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547832/go-through-all-the-userforms-of-a-workbook)

Comment: it might be easier to change your algorithm? Instead of unloading the form when cancel is pressed, ask before and unload only if the answer is yes.